# Conditional ROW NUMBER or COMBINE GROUP BYs

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions, row-number

I need to GROUP BY two different columns and combine.  Furthermore,  IF a **size** with a different **group_id** matches another **size**, then I want to include **ALL** of those rows for that **group_id**.

For example, since **55** is in group_id **10** and group_id **20** I want to include all of the results in group_id **20** (IE 55,88,55,88).

```
p_id  | group_id | size | the_date    
------+----------+-----------+--------
1     |    10    |  55  | 2012-10-24
1     |    10    |  54  | 2014-08-09
1     |    20    |  55  | 2013-05-20
1     |    20    |  88  | 2014-05-20
1     |    20    |  55  | 2015-05-20
1     |    30    |  33  | 2014-05-20
1     |    30    |  55  | 2015-05-20
1     |    30    |  33  | 2015-05-20
1     |    40    |  99  | 2015-05-20
```

I've looked at some of the [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005164/group-by-different-values) on stack AND tried using `row_number` and `first_value` but nothing has worked.  Below is my desired result.

```
p_id  | group_id | size |       group_id_arr         |         size_arr            |  date_arr    
------+----------+------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
1     |    10    |   55 | {10,20,30,20,10,30,30,20}  |  {55,55,33,88,55,55,33,55}  | {2012-10-24,2013-05-20,2014-05-20,2014-05-20,2014-08-09,2015-05-20,2015-05-20,2015-05-20}
1     |    40    |   99 |          {40}              |            {99}             | {2015-05-20}
```

Here is my [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=1952289fcda3d5774838a3f7a52cfcc9) where I am trying to achieve the following so I can aggregrate.

```
 rn   |   p_id   | group_id | size | the_date    
------+----------+----------+------+-----------
1     |    1     |    10    |  55  | 2012-10-24     
2     |    1     |    20    |  55  | 2013-05-20     
3     |    1     |    30    |  33  | 2014-05-20     
4     |    1     |    20    |  88  | 2014-05-20     
5     |    1     |    10    |  54  | 2014-08-09     
6     |    1     |    30    |  55  | 2015-05-20     
7     |    1     |    30    |  33  | 2015-05-20     
8     |    1     |    20    |  55  | 2015-05-20     
1     |    1     |    40    |  99  | 2015-05-20
```

Please let me know if you have any questions. I'm open to all approaches, thanks.

Comment: Please rephrase your condition. So far it looks like ```SELECT min(group_id) as group_id, size, array_agg(group_id) AS group_id_arr, array_agg(size) AS size_arr FROM base_table GROUP BY size;``` is your query

Comment: What aber the pair(10,54)? I cannot find the 54 in your size array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quiet sure about the ordering in the final arrays but this should be a detail you can fix:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=6f2da5d0900045d8a47914ab1e4bd115)

```
WITH sizes as (
    SELECT group_id, the_date, array_agg(size) sizes
    FROM base_table
    GROUP BY group_id, the_date
)
SELECT 
    a_group_id, 
    array_agg(b_group_id order by the_date), 
    array_agg(size order by the_date) as sizes, 
    array_agg(the_date order by the_date)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.group_id as a_group_id, 
        b.group_id as b_group_id, 
        unnest(b.sizes) size, b.the_date
    FROM sizes a 
    INNER JOIN sizes b 
    ON a.sizes && b.sizes
) s
GROUP BY a_group_id
```

1. Aggregate the sizes per `group_id`
2. Cross join the aggregates with themself where one size array has at least one member with another. That gives you a table that you expected and decribed.
3. Grouping by the `group_id`.

Comment: This got me there, thank you. I had to remove the `GROUP BY` **the_date** in the first CTE... Here is the new [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a9ee9b9697ec027a1ad571dfaf674f0f)

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t.id as p_id,min(t.group_id) as group_id, t1.size as size,array_agg(t.size) as size_arr,array_agg(t.group_id) as grp_arr, array_agg(t.date_column) as date_arr from t
 join 
 (select distinct group_id as grp_id, size from t where size=99 or size=55) t1 
 on t1.grp_id=t.group_id 
 group by t.id ,t1.size;
```

Check this one :)